# Creating a Report from a raw data/ log file in R

Tags: r

I need a assistance to convert a raw data of log file in to a Report.

Here is the raw data:

```
Data <- "Date   Generated_Time  User_Name   sas
1   3/24/2020 11:47 EMP1    Login
2   3/24/2020 16:38 EMP1    Login
3   3/24/2020 16:38 EMP1    Logout
4   3/25/2020 2:16  EMP1    Login
5   3/25/2020 2:16  EMP1    Logout
6   3/24/2020 6:51  EMP3    Logout
7   3/24/2020 8:28  EMP3    Login
8   3/24/2020 11:30 EMP3    Logout
9   3/24/2020 21:55 EMP3    Login
10  3/24/2020 23:10 EMP3    Logout
11  3/25/2020 2:34  EMP3    Login
12  3/24/2020 10:05 EMP2    Login
13  3/24/2020 10:18 EMP2    Logout
14  3/24/2020 12:46 EMP2    Login
15  3/24/2020 14:14 EMP2    Logout
16  3/24/2020 17:54 EMP2    Login
17  3/24/2020 19:39 EMP2    Logout
18  3/24/2020 23:15 EMP2    Login
19  3/25/2020 0:18  EMP2    Logout
20  3/25/2020 3:37  EMP2    Login
21  3/25/2020 3:37  EMP2    Logout
22  3/25/2020 3:38  EMP2    Login
"
Data <- read.table(textConnection(
object = Data), 
header = TRUE, 
sep = "", 
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I would like an output like below:

[image]

Here is one assumption:

If subsequently an Employee login/logout time not found than we will consider login time and logout time would be same.

I would really appreciate it if you can help me enhance the logic as well. because the logfile consist of multiple shifts data.

Comment: I think Joining can help you achieve this.

Comment: Not much helpful for me @nikki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difficult part is to match the shift accurately, once you do that then it is easy to do rest of the calculations.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

Data %>%
  group_by(User_Name) %>%
  #Thanks to @GGamba for simplification of grp
  mutate(grp = cumsum(sas == 'Login')) %>%
  unite(DateTime, Date, Generated_Time, sep = " ") %>%
  group_by(User_Name, grp) %>%
  complete(sas = c('Login', 'Logout')) %>%
  fill(DateTime, .direction = "updown") %>%
  mutate(DateTime = mdy_hm(DateTime)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = sas, values_from = DateTime) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(Active_Time = seconds_to_period(Logout - Login))


#   User_Name   grp Login               Logout              Active_Time
#   <chr>     <int> <dttm>              <dttm>              <Period>   
# 1 EMP1          1 2020-03-24 11:47:00 2020-03-24 11:47:00 0S         
# 2 EMP1          2 2020-03-24 16:38:00 2020-03-24 16:38:00 0S         
# 3 EMP1          3 2020-03-25 02:16:00 2020-03-25 02:16:00 0S         
# 4 EMP2          1 2020-03-24 10:05:00 2020-03-24 10:18:00 13M 0S     
# 5 EMP2          2 2020-03-24 12:46:00 2020-03-24 14:14:00 1H 28M 0S  
# 6 EMP2          3 2020-03-24 17:54:00 2020-03-24 19:39:00 1H 45M 0S  
# 7 EMP2          4 2020-03-24 23:15:00 2020-03-25 00:18:00 1H 3M 0S   
# 8 EMP2          5 2020-03-25 03:37:00 2020-03-25 03:37:00 0S         
# 9 EMP2          6 2020-03-25 03:38:00 2020-03-25 03:38:00 0S         
#10 EMP3          1 2020-03-24 06:51:00 2020-03-24 06:51:00 0S         
#11 EMP3          2 2020-03-24 08:28:00 2020-03-24 11:30:00 3H 2M 0S   
#12 EMP3          3 2020-03-24 21:55:00 2020-03-24 23:10:00 1H 15M 0S  
#13 EMP3          4 2020-03-25 02:34:00 2020-03-25 02:34:00 0S
```

We `complete` the rows by adding whichever of `'Login'` or `'Logout'` is absent. Combine date and time values, `fill` the `NA` values with the previous values and subtract the `Login` and `Logout` values.

Comment: seems like a perfect solution. however i am unable to replicate because of the below 2 errors: "could not find function "pivot_wider" and "Error in match.arg(.direction) : 'arg' should be one of “down”, “up”"

Comment: You need to install `tidyr` to latest version using `install.packages('tidyr')`

Comment: I'd simplify `grp` with `cumsum(sas == 'Login')`. With your method we always start at 1, but maybe that's not really needed.

Comment: Thanks for the way out... now need to marry up some logic to identify the shifts as well. great...